# How to make a USB device available to a QEMU guest?

Tags: permissions, qemu, libvirt, virt-manager, gnome-boxes

I am trying to make my laptop camera accessible by a guest system on it.

With the guest system not running, I open it in `virt-manager`, go to "Show virtual hardware details" → "Add Hardware" → "USB Host Device". Here I choose my camera (001:002 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HD User Facing) and click "Finish". The procedure seems to be the same as [described in the KVM documentation](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/USB_Host_Device_Assigned_to_Guest#Managed.2C_using_virt-manager).

This results in the following stanza added to the XML config of the guest machine.

```xml
<hostdev mode="subsystem" type="usb" managed="yes">
  <source>
    <vendor id="0x04f2"/>
    <product id="0xb6dd"/>
  </source>
  <address type="usb" bus="0" port="6"/>
</hostdev>
```

This looks correct according to the [Red Hat's manual on attaching and updating a device with `virsh`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/virtualization_administration_guide/sect-managing_guest_virtual_machines_with_virsh-attaching_and_updating_a_device_with_virsh).

However, I cannot run the guest with it because `qemu` is denied permission.

```
Error starting domain: internal error: qemu unexpectedly closed the monitor: 2022-03-13T05:27:57.240470Z qemu-system-x86_64: -device {"driver":"usb-host","hostdevice":"/dev/bus/usb/001/002","id":"hostdev0","bus":"usb.0","port":"6"}: failed to open /dev/bus/usb/001/002: Permission denied

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/gnu/store/r9jxh3pv020qa05pza3jiky2vppn68mx-virt-manager-3.2.0/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 65, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/gnu/store/r9jxh3pv020qa05pza3jiky2vppn68mx-virt-manager-3.2.0/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 101, in tmpcb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/gnu/store/r9jxh3pv020qa05pza3jiky2vppn68mx-virt-manager-3.2.0/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 57, in newfn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/gnu/store/r9jxh3pv020qa05pza3jiky2vppn68mx-virt-manager-3.2.0/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 1329, in startup
    self._backend.create()
  File "/gnu/store/7c16ipd35j0fdl6mrjbg3v9zsn8iivi0-python-libvirt-7.9.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 1353, in create
    raise libvirtError('virDomainCreate() failed')
libvirt.libvirtError: internal error: qemu unexpectedly closed the monitor: 2022-03-13T05:27:57.240470Z qemu-system-x86_64: -device {"driver":"usb-host","hostdevice":"/dev/bus/usb/001/002","id":"hostdev0","bus":"usb.0","port":"6"}: failed to open /dev/bus/usb/001/002: Permission denied
```

The device that it is trying to access is correct:

```
$ lsusb -s 001:002
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b6dd Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HD User Facing
```

The device is owned by `root`. It seems that read access is not enough for `qemu`.

```
$ LC_ALL=C ls -l /dev/bus/usb/001/002
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 1 Mar 13 06:15 /dev/bus/usb/001/002
```

My guess is that the device is owned by `root` for a good security reason. Similarly, `virt-manager` does not prompt me to run `qemu` as `root`. How do I safely manage permissions to allow the guest access the camera?

---

Another approach, which I initially tried, was to use GNOME Boxes to enable access to the camera device in the respective guest settings. It tries to use SPICE USB redirection, which is similar to what is [described in the SPICE user manual](https://www.spice-space.org/spice-user-manual.html#_configuration_3), but uses `qemu-xhci` host adapter instead of `ich9-ehci1`. However, when I try to flip the switch in the guest settings for the camera device, it just notifies that its redirection failed. Here are the relevant parts in my guest machine configuration, which seem to be OK:

```xml
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="qemu-xhci" ports="15">
      <alias name="usb"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x02" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </controller>
```

```xml
    <redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
      <alias name="redir0"/>
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="2"/>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
      <alias name="redir1"/>
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="3"/>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
      <alias name="redir2"/>
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="4"/>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
      <alias name="redir3"/>
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="5"/>
    </redirdev>
```

---

So, how can I make the camera available to the guest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a [Debian machine](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/spice-client-glib-usb-acl-helper), `spice-client-glib-usb-acl-helper` from SPICE GTK is used to pass through USB devices to VMs on demand or per configuration. It validates ACLs (Linux Access Control Lists) via the PolicyKit kit.

The helper is invoked by the program that the user runs with user privileges but determines access to privileged resources, so it needs to be set setuid to be able to run with elevated privileges. On a Debian machine, it is set setuid during the installation process:

```
$ LC_ALL=C ls -l /usr/libexec/spice-client-glib-usb-acl-helper
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 18512 Mar  1  2023 /usr/libexec/spice-client-glib-usb-acl-helper
```

Note the `s` for the setuid bit in the permissions.

---

However, on a Guix System, the installation is assumed to be carried by an unprivileged user. So, additional configuration is necessary after installation. Furthermore, the Guix store cannot contain setuid programs [for security reasons](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Setuid-Programs.html). Thus, the setuid programs need to be declared in the system configuration file.

Here is an inelegant example of such additions to make the SPICE USB passthrough work on a Guix System:

```
(use-modules …
             (gnu system setuid)
             (gnu packages spice))
(use-service-modules …
             virtualization dbus)

(operating-system …
  (services
   (append (list …
                 (service libvirt-service-type)
                 (service virtlog-service-type)
                 (simple-service 'spice-polkit polkit-service-type (list spice-gtk)))))
  (setuid-programs
    (append (list (setuid-program
                    (program (file-append spice-gtk "/libexec/spice-client-glib-usb-acl-helper"))))
            %setuid-programs)))
```

Note the line extending the policy and then a snippet to extend the list of the default setuid programs.

With such a configuration, it is possible to use the switches in the interface in GNOME Boxes to pass through USB devices to the guest machine.

Answer (score 2):

I found that adding the device from `/dev/bus/usb/` to `kvm` group allows using the GUI switches in GNOME Boxes or `virt-manager` to make it available to the VM.

The bus number and the device number can be identified with `lsusb`. The device is available by its number in the directory named by its bus number in `/dev/bus/usb/`. For example,

```
$ lsusb | grep HD
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b6dd Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HD User Facing
$ sudo chgrp kvm /dev/bus/usb/001/002
$ LC_ALL=C ls -l /dev/bus/usb/001/002
crw-rw-r-- 1 root kvm 189, 1 Apr  2 17:26 /dev/bus/usb/001/002
```

This modification does not survive re-attaching the device to the host or rebooting the host machine.

Comment: Might want to have a look at [udev rules](https://askubuntu.com/a/15643) to set owners and permissions when they're added to the host.